# Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll using Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, python.net

I am having an issue using the pythonnet module within Spyder

I am trying to use pythonnet within a program I am writing.

I am using Spyder (5.2.2) that I have installed using Anaconda, running python 3.9.7
I have installed pythonnet using pip install python net from a command prompt within the anaconda environment.

If I then open Spyder I can run the command:
import clr

with no issues.

However if I then run any kind of script within spyder and either within that script or subsequently run the command
import clr

I get the following

```
import clr
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\oliver.warlow\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3780\2426853703.py", line 1, in <module>
    import clr

  File "C:\Users\oliver.warlow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clr.py", line 6, in <module>
    load()

  File "C:\Users\oliver.warlow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pythonnet\__init__.py", line 144, in load
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll")

RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll


Failed to initialize pythonnet: System.InvalidOperationException: This property must be set before runtime is initialized
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
   at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
   at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

thanks

oli

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I am facing exactly the same problem

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find a solution to make it work within Spyder unfortunately so I am having to execute my code in an external system terminal

Comment: Workaround is to close the console.  The new console will run the script once, then close that console...